# How does System.Data.SQLite deal with .NET Data Types?

Tags: .net, sqlite, system.data.sqlite

I'm struggling to find documentation around System.Data.SQLite's behaviour in regards to the various .NET data types.

For example, how does System.Data.SQLite store .NET Booleans in an SQLite database? There are several possible methods:

- Integers **0** and **1**
- Integers **0** and **–1**
- Text **'True'** and **'False'**
- Text **'T'** and **'F'**
- Text **'Y'** and **'N'**
- etc...

And vice-versa – how are Booleans parsed out of SQLite? Does System.Data.SQLite expect a certain format? What is that format?

The lack of documentation around this is frustrating. Maybe I'm not looking in the right places?

**NOTE:** This is not a question about Booleans specifically. I'm looking for documentation *that explains behaviours for all .NET data types*.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

I suggest you start with the driver-agnostic [SQLite documentation on the subject](https://www.sqlite.org/datatype3.html). It explains the way booleans should be stored, and the different datetime serialization schemes, for example.

For more details, System.Data.SQLite is open source, and while a bit crufty around certain edges, is generally quite easy to read.

For example, the `GetValue()` method (part of the ADO.NET `IDataReader` interface that's implemented) in [SQLiteDataReader.cs](https://system.data.sqlite.org/index.html/artifact/18f60c317bbdfb16) calls a method named `GetSQLiteType()`, then does a bit more auto-detection depending on some connection flags.

`GetSQLiteType()` and friends all lead back to the [SQLiteConvert](https://system.data.sqlite.org/index.html/artifact/e85cd403f4127f42) class, which does the actual type conversions and detection. The conversions are all defined there (starting about halfway through, after a lot of date manipulation helpers). Eventually you reach this function which is of particular relevance to your question:

```
internal static TypeAffinity TypeToAffinity(Type typ)
{
  TypeCode tc = Type.GetTypeCode(typ);
  if (tc == TypeCode.Object)
  {
    if (typ == typeof(byte[]) || typ == typeof(Guid))
      return TypeAffinity.Blob;
    else
      return TypeAffinity.Text;
  }
  return _typecodeAffinities[(int)tc];
}

private static TypeAffinity[] _typecodeAffinities = {
  TypeAffinity.Null,     // Empty (0)
  TypeAffinity.Blob,     // Object (1)
  TypeAffinity.Null,     // DBNull (2)
  TypeAffinity.Int64,    // Boolean (3)
  TypeAffinity.Int64,    // Char (4)
  TypeAffinity.Int64,    // SByte (5)
  TypeAffinity.Int64,    // Byte (6)
  TypeAffinity.Int64,    // Int16 (7)
  TypeAffinity.Int64,    // UInt16 (8)
  TypeAffinity.Int64,    // Int32 (9)
  TypeAffinity.Int64,    // UInt32 (10)
  TypeAffinity.Int64,    // Int64 (11)
  TypeAffinity.Int64,    // UInt64 (12)
  TypeAffinity.Double,   // Single (13)
  TypeAffinity.Double,   // Double (14)
  TypeAffinity.Double,   // Decimal (15)
  TypeAffinity.DateTime, // DateTime (16)
  TypeAffinity.Null,     // ?? (17)
  TypeAffinity.Text      // String (18)
};
```

In general, integer types will get properly mapped to SQLite's (64-bit) integers and back, and ditto for strings. `byte[]` arrays and `Guid`s will work transparently too, though both are stored as blobs. Boolean values are mapped to 1 (true) and 0 (false) integers. And all of the SQLite datetime representations are supported, and more: see the `Bind_DateTime()` method in [SQLite3.cs](https://system.data.sqlite.org/index.html/artifact/fe658f779c2ce36a).

Comment: Wow, now we're talking. Thank you. I just started doing some tests (inserting typed parameters into columns with no affinity), to reverse engineer the behaviours. You just saved me a bit of valuable time :-)

Comment: On a related note, I just discovered that the data types specified in `CREATE TABLE` SQL *have meaning to System.Data.SQLite*. A column defined as INT16 has some meaning to SQLite itself (you get INTEGER Affinity) *but* System.Data.SQLite will notice the INT16 definition and parse to `Int16` if it can. All this is such valuable information. I'm tempted to blog this somewhere...

Comment: @misha256: Could be a good idea for the next person :-) I admit that reading the source is not exactly as pleasant as well-written documentation would be!